# How to recalculate uploaded files' sizes in KB and update the values in the database?

Tags: 7, database, files

I use a shell command to look for all uploaded `JPEG` files above 500 K.B. (originals) and do JPEG compression on them. They get smaller in size, but Drupal still shows the originally uploaded file size. How to force a recalculation and update the database accordingly after JPEG optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7 managed files have their `filesize` property updated upon saving in the [`file_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save/7.x) function. So you can just load/save each resized files to have it updated in the DB accordingly.

```
//@TODO: Get list of $fids corresponding to resized-files
foreach ($fids as $fid) {
  $file = file_load($fid);
  // $file->filesize reflects old size
  file_save($file);
  // $file->filesize now reflects new size
}
```